# apex:iframe doesn't allow display-capture

Tags: visualforce, iframe

Can you tell me please how to enable display-capture in Visualforce page?

HTML

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block">
        <apex:iframe src="" html-allow="camera; microphone; fullscreen; display-capture" scrolling="true" id="obIframe" height="1200px" width="100%"
        html-sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-top-navigation" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

JS

```
const iframePermissionsParameter = '?iframe_allow=' + encodeURIComponent("geolocation *; camera *; microphone *; fullscreen *; display-capture *");

const url = `${Endpoint}/auth/${launchToken}/${credentials.siteId}/${iframePermissionsParameter}`;
document.getElementById("obIframe").src = url;
```

When I run my component, I see in the console that the wrapper aloha-page:iframe has no display-capture permission =>

```
<iframe force-alohapage_alohapage="" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" name="vfFrameId_1651674422240" title="accessibility title" allowfullscreen="true" lang="en-US" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to use `iframe` instead of `apex:iframe` if you need greater control over the generated HTML.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for your answer, but i changed tag to iframe and nothing has changed, I think my problem is that when the visualforce component is rendered the permissions are applied automatically on the top level, iframe force-alohapage_alohapage and there is no display-capture permission, and therefore on the bottom level I can not add this permission, can you suggest something?